# Migrate from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core (ASP.NET MVC5 project to Blazor WebAssembly(.NET Core Hosted))

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, blazor-webassembly

Good day everyone

Here's my scenario, I was given a task to maintain and update a project that was developed by a previously resigned developer, which I was hired to be his replace, unfortunately, we didn't meet as he was resigned for 3 months now, Now I have to maintain his project which fine with and his code is clean and maintainable, now we have project to update our system from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core or .NET 6. all of the projects are using Entity Framework, for me, I only have experience on developing on Entity Framework Core, as I'm using ADO.NET during my .NET Framework days. Now all of the project's databases are code first in entity framework and has a migration history with it, for projects, I will recode it on Blazor WebAssembly (.Net Core Hosted), and I want to use the existing database, but I have no experience on migrating from Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core, I want to try the database first approach, but this might cause a problem when I want to update the database using Migration.

Also, the database has also had an Identity/AspNetUsers

Can someone teach me on what's the best approach for this?

Thanks, and regards.

I'm planning to use database first but this might not get the migration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For migrating the EF 6 database first to EF core application, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-database).

> Also, the database has also had an Identity/AspNetUsers,Also, the database has also had an Identity/AspNetUsers

For migrating authentication and identity to ASP.NET core, I suggest you could follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0).